# Chosing method vs decorator in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class method which needs to perform some basic validation upfront prior to doing a "real" operations.

One obvious choice of implementation is:

```
   def _validator(self, args):
       do-validation

   def method_real(self, args):
       self._validator(args)
       do-real-thing
```

Other one is:

```
   def validator(fn):
       def _validate(*args, **kwargs):
           do-validation
           return fn(*args, **kwargs)
       return _validate

   @validator
   def method_real(self, args):
       do-real-thing
```

Though use of decorator here fits in and gives a better code readability and organization, I want the opinion on whether or not to use decorator just for one method. This decorator can not be used by other methods in the class as it does very specific validation for only that method.

Thoughts?

Comment: I was just editing but you beat me to that Tanveer. :). Thx anyways

Comment: If a method cannot possibly be repurposed by another method, you should include it as a closure inside that method. For example [something like this](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/6b10f28c0a7abebb8514)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you don't *need* a decorator which is always a great sign that you don't *want* one. That's just your basic [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle but there's more to it than that. With decorators, there's nuance there that you might not be aware of that can end up doing more harm than good. It can make debugging problematic to say the least. [Graham Dumpleton has an incredibly informative series of posts](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/implementing-universal-decorator.html) on what you can get yourself into when using decorators (warning: **very** in-depth).

If I were you, I'd simply inline the logic if it's simple or create a separate method/function if it's not. And if you really just want to make the module that's consuming this behavior to be "cleaner", then create a new module with this validation logic and import.

On the other hand if you *know* that you need a decorator then you probably do *want* one.